Making colored CA glue
I have a project where I patch up small holes in media with super glue. I need to be able to see where I patched the hole later on, so I figured having the super glue be colored would help. So I need to determine how to tint/color super glue. A quick search showed me that there are already numerous black colored super glue in the market. Among them is this: https://bsi-inc.com/sds_pdf/sds_ic_2000.pdf (not endorsing the product itself). According to Composition, it uses carbon black to attain the black color.
I have a spare bottle of super glue. Can I just add some carbon black/soot to it & expect it to behave like plain super glue? Would the soot disperse well? Or, would it perhaps the soot will catalyze the super glue to polymerize exothermically?
If soot doesn't work, what else can I use to tint/color plain super glue?

test a sample ..

For reducing the depth of guitar top-nut (where the strings leave the fretboard on the way to the tuners) slot depth filling the slot with backing powder and applying CA glue is a popular fix. I've done it. I guess you just need a particle that's made from a material that CA would normally work on. There are also many videos of people using cotton wool as a large gap filler on  things like kitchen cabinet hinge pockets which have been ripped out and solidifying it with CA.

I fee like this would be better on a craft forum.  Use colored plastic.

Mixing may need to occur in a contained amd controlled atmosphere.

You can buy powdered tempera paint at craft stores in bulk. try mixing a bit into the glue as if it were a thickener.
Epoxy can also be tinted (and thickened too) with paint powder like this.
